# UIViewContainer transformation changes after UIButton title is changed

Tags: ios, swift

I have the storyboard in the below screenshot.

[image]

The gray area is a `UIViewContainer`. `UIGestureRegonizers` are enabling the zooming and the moving of the `UIViewContainer` through Pan-Pinch gestures. The location of the buttons are fixed in the bottom with constraints, the `UIViewContainer` has flexible size and connected to buttons and the safe are with constraints.

So here is the problem: First, I zoom into a part of the UIViewContainer and then, I change the title of the up-right button. Right after that, for some reason that I need help with, the container moves about 10 pixels to the right. I am sure that no lifecycle function is called after the `button.setTitle()` function. I think it can be the problem that the container does some kind of a relayout.

[Here is a dummy app](https://github.com/Barsovich/dummyApp) where I reproduced the same behavior. After you move the container to somewhere with a pan gesture and click the button, the button title changes and the view is moved back to center. I want the view to stay where it is.

How can I disable the layout after the button title is changed?

```
@IBAction func handlePinchGestures(pinchGestureRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = pinchGestureRecognizer.view {
        switch pinchGestureRecognizer.state {
        case .changed:
            let pinchCenter = CGPoint(x: pinchGestureRecognizer.location(in: view).x - view.bounds.midX,
                                      y: pinchGestureRecognizer.location(in: view).y - view.bounds.midY)
            let transform = view.transform.translatedBy(x: pinchCenter.x, y: pinchCenter.y)
                .scaledBy(x: pinchGestureRecognizer.scale, y: pinchGestureRecognizer.scale)
                .translatedBy(x: -pinchCenter.x, y: -pinchCenter.y)
            view.transform = transform
            pinchGestureRecognizer.scale = 1
            imageLayerContainer.subviews.forEach({ (subview: UIView) -> Void in subview.setNeedsDisplay() })
        default:
            return
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func handlePanGesturesWithTwoFingers(panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = panGestureRecognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    panGestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

Comment: Better if you upload screen shot here on stack rather than any other site.

Comment: I am not allowed to upload images right now, because I am a new member.

Comment: You can upload image and but text with hyperlink will be shown. I can edit it for you.. Check https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7gQn.png

Comment: I tried to do that but stack rejected. It would be great if you could do that.

Comment: Can you add dummy project on github so that we can check what actually happening?

Comment: Added the dummy project.

Comment: you need to share link with us too.  .

Comment: Can't you see the link in the question?